# Children's fantasy story : Jungle explorer encounters strange villages

Tags: story-identification

This was a children's book I read in 5th grade a long time ago.
The story is about a jungle explorer making his way through many dangers.

The first danger was a plant that would grab your feet and rip you in half,
but the explorer was wearing 2 pairs of boots and so slipped away. He then grabbed some sticks from a tree and uses them to check for any more of the plants as he walks. He then is trapped by another beastie, but escapes because it is allergic to the sticks.

He then encounters a village of lazy people who eat anything they catch, so he runs away. He runs to a village where the only things they eat are ideas (they are going to kill the explorer until he eats an apple, this scares the villagers into thinking he will try to eat *them*).

One other thing he defeats is a group monster. The individuals walk in a line, and have only one eye, in the belly of the last monster. All the other monsters have a hole in the middle so the eye can see... even around corners. The only way to kill it/them is to shoot the eye, The explorer slowly backs up in a straight line until he can see the eye and.. kills the monster.

This is a really trippy book, and the illustrations are really colorful.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wroshyr_tree ?

Comment: uh-oh.  yep, looks like I *don't* remember the right name. rats.